# Google sheet: joint text from multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets

On a **new tab**, for each row, I want to enclose the text of all the columns from my **dataset** tab that contains the word "WORD" in its 2nd row.
I cannot directly target the column letter, and the number and place of columns containing "WORD" will change over time.
I've tried with HLOOKUP and QUERY, I can't get there.

**Example**

**dataset**

| # | Another header | Another header |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xxxx | WORD | WORD |
| 1 | contentA | contentC |
| 2 | contentB | contentD |

**new tab**

| # | ALL WORD |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | contentA ContentC |
| 2 | contentB ContentD |

Comment: answer updated..

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:B);;9^9))
```

[image]

or:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:B);;9^9))))
```

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(
 dataset!A2:99999; REGEXMATCH(dataset!1:1; "(?:)WORD")));;9^9)))))
```

[image]

Comment: you gotta use the word "WORD" i think...?

Comment: @MattKing could be. hard to tell

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(dataset!3:100000,dataset!2:2="WORD")),,9^9)))
```

the use of the number 100000 is intentional, it should be more rows than you'd ever have.